# natural transformation for double dual vector space

Tags: category-theory

The definition of natural transformation $n$ are maps from functors f,g: $C\rightarrow D$ where C,D are categories. More specifically, for each x in f(C) (where f(C) $\in$ D), $n_x$ are maps from D to D. However,the example that $V \rightarrow V^{**}$ is natural doesn't seem to match the definition,it goes from functor Id：$V \rightarrow V$ to dual:$V \rightarrow V^{**}$ but $V \neq V^{**}$ ,so what is D?

Comment: $C$ and $D$ are both the category $\text{Vect}$. The identity and double dual functors are functors $\text{Vect} \to \text{Vect}$. I also don't understand your second sentence: the components of a natural transformation are maps $\eta_c : F(c) \to G(c)$, indexed by the objects of $C$.

Comment: Thanks! so V and V** here are just deemed subsets of Vect,which is a bit confusing for starters

Comment: They're not subsets, they're objects in $\text{Vect}$.